# Service Area Analysis with Google Distance Matrix API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gis, google-directions-api, google-distancematrix-api

Can I use Google Map APIs to do service area analysis as it is possible in ArcGIS? I mean getting all the streets that can be reached within for example 10 minutes drive from a certain location.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create an isochrone (a shape drawn using a travel time area) using an API so that it can show all possible locations reachable in this time. The shape is then editable by departure / arrival time, mode of transport and maximum time to travel.

The API has 3 main functions that enable it to help solve the service distance area problem:

- TimeMap - Returns polygons that relate to time area. These can be a single isochrone or multiple (i.e. where 2 people can live or where someone should be to get to 2 offices)
- TimeFilter - returns times, true distance and fare cost for 1000's of lat / longs in one request
- Routes - much like TimeFilter - but returns the drawable and readable route.

Take a look at [TravelTime API](http://www.traveltimeplatform.com/developers-traveltime-api-documentation/)

(Disclaimer: I work for the creator of this API)
[Example isochrone here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaRSi.jpg)